# Batch files always crash when entering a space

Tags: windows, batch-file, crash, space

I have been programming a batch file to simulate some kind of game, but it always crash (or simply close) when entering and submitting the Space or just nothing at all. How can I fix this from happening? Example:

```
set /p option=Option:
```

Then I would have:

```
Option:
```

And I need to enter something, but in this case, if I hit Enter without entering anything (or Space) it will close itself.

=== EDIT ===

The full code here:

```
@echo off
cd Desktop
md TestFolder
goto main

:main
cls
title Test
echo.
echo Enter your name below
echo.
set /p name=Name:
if %name% == %name% set name=%name% & goto finish

:finish
echo.
echo Thank you for entering your name.
echo Press any key to close the window.
pause >nul
exit
```

The problem will lie in "set /p name=" as when batch prompts you for your name (the "Name:" part), if you hit Enter without anything entered, it will close.

Comment: How should we help? You show one line of code which will never crash. It could be useful to see the code which fails

Comment: Yes, this IS the code, in fact, every code that's similar to this will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are after.

The line `IF NOT DEFINED name GOTO main` checks to see if the user just pressed the Enter key without typing anything and if that is true then will return to the `:main` label and prompt the user again to enter a name.

The line `IF "%name%"==" " GOTO main` checks if the user just entered 1 `space` character and if so, then will return to the `:main` label also to prompt the user again.

```
:main
cls
title Test
echo.
echo Enter your name below
echo.
set /p name=Name:
IF NOT DEFINED name GOTO main
IF "%name%"==" " GOTO main

:finish
echo.
echo Thank you for entering your name.
echo Press any key to close the window.
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly and now batch never closes, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

This is the line which makes the trouble:

```
if %name% == %name% set name=%name% & goto finish
```

If you just hit enter at the `set /p name=Name:`, %name% will be empty.
So the line above will execute as:

```
if == set name= & goto finish
```

Of course, this will never work
To make the syntax correct, use:

```
if "%name%" == "%name%" set name=%name% & goto finish
```

Ok, this was the Syntax-part.
but what do you try to do? If a is equal to a then make a = a ??

Comment: If a is equal to a then make a = a ??
Yeah, you can never be sure. Since #define a b was possible in C++ you want to double check that :-)

Comment: Note that the `space` before the `&` will be included in the `name` variable.  One method to eliminate that is to use quotes as in `set "name=%name%"` or put the & directly after the variable as in `set name=%name%&`

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I'd like to mark this as my answer too, but unfortunately we're only allowed to mark one. I shall vote up your answer then, because the one I marked as Answer answered what I mainly wanted to do. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You have given us next to nothing to go on, but I'll make an educated guess. If you are running the file by double clicking the file (or a shortcut), from the desktop or from Windows Explorer, then your console will close automatically when the program reaches an end point. The end point could be due to your code logic, or it could be due to a fatal syntax error. It will close before you have a chance to read any messages that are printed.

The solution is to change how you run your game, especially while you are developing. Run the console directly by going to Start->All Programs->Accessories and select **cmd.exe**. Use `CD` to navigate to the folder where your game resides, and then enter the name of the batch file to run it. Now the console will remain open when the game ends, and you will be able to see all messages and debug much easier.